# angular how to upload image and retrieve image as string in edit mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular-material

I am learning building application using angular and asp.net core using these videos on [this link](https://www.freetutorialsus.com/building-applications-with-angular-11-and-asp-net-core-5/) - Unit Forms, lesson -"Selecting Images From the Computer" by Felipe Gavilan - on VSCode. Everything works fine except the edit of a a component with image. The tutorial creates two interfaces(two models)  - one for retrieving image as string, other for creating an image by uploading it. When I run the app, I get the error as below **but the same code works in tutorial, I don't know why**
[image: Error]

> Type 'actorDTO' is not assignable to type 'actorCreationDTO'
> Types of property 'picture' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'File'.
> <app-form-actor [model]="model" (onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)">
> src/app/actors/edit-actor/edit-actor.component.ts:7:24
> templateUrl: './edit-actor.component.html',
> Error occurs in the template of component EditActorComponent.

The error in the line below is due to the two model interfaces (1)actorCreationDTO which has "picture" of type File(for creating and uploading an image) and (2)actorDTO which has "picture" of type string(for retrieving in edit mode)

> <app-form-actor [model]="model" (onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)">

**actors.model.ts**

```
            export interface actorCreationDTO{
        name:string;
        dateOfBirth:Date;
        picture:File;
        biography?:string;
        }

        export interface actorDTO{
            name:string;
            dateOfBirth:Date;
            picture:string;
            biography?:string;

            }
```

**form-actor.component.html**

```
            <form (submit)="saveChanges()" [formGroup]="form">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Name*</mat-label>
                <input formControlName="name" matInput>
                <mat-error>The name is required</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Date Of Birth</mat-label>
                <input formControlName="dateOfBirth" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
            <h4>Select Picture</h4>
            <app-input-img 
        [urlCurrentImage]="model?.picture"  (onImageSelected)="onImageSelected($event)"></app-input-img>
        
        <!-- <app-input-img 
            (onImageSelected)="onImageSelected($event)"></app-input-img>
            -->
            <h4>Biography</h4>
            <app-input-markdown [markdownContent]="model?.biography" (changeMarkdown)="changeMarkdown($event)"></app-input-markdown>

        <div><button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save Changes</button>
        <a mat-stroked-button routerLink="/actors" >Cancel</a>
        </div>
        </form>
```

**form-actor.component.ts**

```
      import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  import { actorCreationDTO } from '../actors.model';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-form-actor',
    templateUrl: './form-actor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-actor.component.css']
  })
  export class FormActorComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }
    form!:FormGroup;
  @Input()
  model!:actorCreationDTO;
    @Output()
    onSaveChanges=new EventEmitter<actorCreationDTO>();
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['',{
          validators:[Validators.required]
        }],
        dateOfBirth:'',
        picture:'',
        biography:''
      });
      if(this.form!==undefined)
      {
        this.form.patchValue(this.model);
      }
    }
    onImageSelected(image: any){
      this.form.get('picture')?.setValue(image);
    }
    changeMarkdown(content: any){
      this.form.get('biography')?.setValue(content);
    }
    saveChanges(){
      this.onSaveChanges.emit(this.form.value);
    }
  }
```

**create-actor.component.html**

```
            <h2>Create Actor</h2>
        <app-form-actor (onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)"></app-form-actor>
```

**create-actor.component.ts**

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { actorCreationDTO } from '../actors.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-create-actor',
      templateUrl: './create-actor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./create-actor.component.css']
    })
    export class CreateActorComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
      saveChanges(actorCreationDTO:actorCreationDTO){
        console.log(actorCreationDTO);

      }
    }
```

**edit-actor.component.html**

```
        <h2>Edit Actor</h2>
    <app-form-actor [model]="model" (onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)"></app-form-actor>
```

**edit-actor.component.ts**

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { actorCreationDTO, actorDTO } from '../actors.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-edit-actor',
      templateUrl: './edit-actor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./edit-actor.component.css']
    })
    export class EditActorComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

    model:actorDTO ={name: 'Tom Holland',dateOfBirth: new Date(), 
    picture:'https://www.nme.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Chris-Evans-Captain-America-696x442.jpg',
    biography:'default value'
            }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.router.navigate(['edit',id], { relativeTo: this.route });

        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>
          {
          // alert(params.id);
          });
      }

   
    saveChanges(actorCreationDTO:actorCreationDTO){
      console.log(actorCreationDTO);

    }

    }
```

**index-actors.component.html**

```
            <h2>Actors</h2>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" routerLink="/actors/create">Create New</button>
```

**index-actors.component.ts**

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-index-actors',
    templateUrl: './index-actors.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./index-actors.component.css']
  })
  export class IndexActorsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems when you bind the data models are not matched

In

> edit-actor.component.ts

Use

```
model: actorCreationDTO = {
    // your object
}
```

Instead of

```
model: actorDTO = {
    // your object
}
```

or, you have to change

In

> form-actor.component.ts

this

```
model!:actorCreationDTO;
```

into this

```
model!:actorDTO;
```